# Add onclick attribute in IE7

Tags: jquery, onclick, internet-explorer-7

```
$(".awp_class_horizantal").attr('onclick', 'changeTextAdd(this.id)');
```

Above code is not working in IE7 but working in remaining browsers.

Can anybody pls suggest me how to add onclick attribute which works in IE7???

```
$(".awp_class_horizantal").click(function() {
            changeTextAdd(this.id);
            });
```

Above code is working but it is giving unresponsive script error for me.

I have to call changeTextAdd function in that function itself.

Thanks

Comment: `.on('click', function() {` should work fine. its better than inline js.

Comment: What is `changeTextAdd`? The way you're binding this is perfectly normal; so the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$(".awp_class_horizantal").prop('onclick', 'changeTextAdd(this.id)');`

for [more info](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11899)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a version of jQuery that supports Internet Explorer 7. I would suggest you try loading jQuery 1.8.3 to be sure. Secondly, be sure to run your code only after the DOM has been loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".aw_class_horizontal").on("click", function () {
        changeTextAdd( this.id );
    });
});
```

Note the updated spelling of "horizontal". That may or may not have been a problem for you depending on what your class was. If you experience any problems beyond this, you should check into what `changeTextAdd` is doing, and see if it can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks Sampson.. I was bindind my click event recursively.. I got the solution thanks

Comment: @vamsi Glad you were able to figure it out; I've seen that issue bite many people.